# how find a valid credit card Specifications?

Tags: credit-card

i'm from iran and here we couldn't buy any credit card.
for signup to many of sites we need a credit card Specifications such as credit card number, cvv2 and expire date.

some sites generates fake creditcard. but Specifications of non of them dont work.

please introduce a good site for this or give me a valid credit card Specifications for signup to these sites.

thanks

Comment: So credit cards aren't available to you and you're asking for a way to provide a fake card number that will work for sites that require payment via credit card?  Or worse yet, a valid number that isn't yours so that someone else will be charged?

Comment: Now I'm waiting for police to read this question OK, I know that this is not going to happen, but it would be fun.

Comment: بابا من 24 سالمه و تو بعضی سایت ها میگن که اطلاعات کردیت کارتتون رو بدین تا تایید بشه که سنتون بالای 18 ساله. به همین دلیل من احتیاج به اطلاعات کردیت کارت جعلی دارم.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my friend please use this site :

```
names.igopaygo.com
```

Comment: oh thanks my friend. but this site didnt help me